# converting XML file into HTML file

Tags: php, html, xml

I have an XML file and i want to print the data as html which contains multiple tags. I have looped the file using foreach but it only prints the tags of the XML file. The text inside the tags are not printing.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Jobs>
    <APPLICATION>
        <ACTION><![CDATA[MODIFY]]></ACTION>
        <JOBID><![CDATA[21494017]]></JOBID>
        <JOBTITLE><![CDATA[dummy MNC&amp;#x27;S of Pune.]]></JOBTITLE>
        <JobDescription><![CDATA[dummy]]></JobDescription>  
        <KEYSKILLS><![CDATA[dummy]]></KEYSKILLS>
        <SUMMARY><![CDATA[dummy]]></SUMMARY>

    </APPLICATION>
    <APPLICATION>
        <ACTION><![CDATA[MODIFY]]></ACTION>
        <JOBID><![CDATA[21494017]]></JOBID>
        <JOBTITLE><![CDATA[dummy MNC&amp;#x27;S of Pune.]]></JOBTITLE>
        <JobDescription><![CDATA[dummy]]></JobDescription>  
        <KEYSKILLS><![CDATA[dummy]]></KEYSKILLS>
        <SUMMARY><![CDATA[dummy]]></SUMMARY>

    </APPLICATION>
    AND SO ON..........................................
</Jobs>
```

The issue i am facing is that when i loop it only print the tags like:

```
 Jobs
 APPLICATION: 
 APPLICATION: 
 APPLICATION: 
 APPLICATION: 
 APPLICATION:
```

Following is the code that i am using to print the XML file:

```
 $xml=simplexml_load_file("fli.xml");
 echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
}
```

I am not able to print the data inside the `APPLICATION`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `APPLICATION` element doesn't contain text. You should do one more inner cycle on `$child` to get the text inside the inner tags. At the moment you're just cycling on the `APPLICATION`s.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("fli.xml");
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{
    foreach($child->children() as $inner) {
        echo $inner->getName() . ": " . $inner. "<br>";
    }
}
```